# I have a function that I want to return multiple object the second the task complete (react native)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

```
export const Upload = async(image) => {
    const filename = `patient/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
    const response = await fetch(image);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const task = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename).put(blob);
    // set progress state
    const taskProgres = (snapshot) => {
      console.log(Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000);
    };

    const taskComplet = () => {
       task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {
        return(snapshot)
      });
    };
    const taskError = (snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot);
    };

    task.on("state_changed", taskProgres, taskError, taskComplet);
  };
```

when calling this function I want it to return when taskProgres finish and when taskComplet finish is that passible and how to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the function to return when the upload is done.

In that case, consider returning `task` itself, which is a promise that resolves when the upload is completed.

---

If you want to return the download URL, you can do that with:

```
  export const Upload = async(image) => {
    const filename = `patient/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
    const response = await fetch(image);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const task = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename).put(blob);

    await task;

    const downloadUrl = await task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()

    return downloadUrl;
  };
```

---

If you want to both handle progress in your calling function, and have it return the resulting download URL, you'll need to pass in a callback as you can't return two results that arrive at different times.

That'd look something like this:

```
  export const Upload = async(image, progressCallback) => {
    const filename = `patient/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
    const response = await fetch(image);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const task = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename).put(blob);
    task.on("state_changed", progressCallback);
    await task;

    const downloadUrl = await task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()

    return downloadUrl;
  };
```

You'd then call it like this:

```
const downloadURL = await Upload(imageURL, (taskSnapshot) => {
  console.log(Math.round(taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalBytes) * 10000)
});
console.log(downloadURL);
```

Comment: and how can I return the taskProgres  before returning downloadUrl because there is a progress bar that I want to display before it upload?

Comment: You can't return two things at different times from a single function call. If you want to control both behaviors, consider passing in callbacks when you call `Upload` - pretty much exactly as the callbacks you pass to Firebase in your existing code.

Comment: I never used callback don't know how to make it work in my function

Comment: I added an example of that too.

Comment: You said I should consider passing a call back function...  how can I do it ?

Comment: That's exactly what the last two snippets in my answer show. Did you try them? What was the problem?

Comment: sorry did not see that you edited the answer there is no problem now thank you